# How to replace comma with new line

Tags: powershell

I am getting input like s1,s2,s3,s4.i am writing it to file.

Tried below way :

```
$ServerList = Get-Content "D:\ServerName.txt"
Clear-Content -Path "D:\ServerName.txt"
[IO.File]::ReadAllText($ServerList) -replace ',',"`r`n" | Out-File "D:\ServerName.txt"
```

But it is not writing anything.

It should replace comma with newline to bring each server in new line.

Please let me know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you clearing the content?
It clears the content of the items and hence the operation next line is not returning anything.

Comment: Before that line i am taking the content of the file.

Comment: ``(Get-Content 'D:\ServerName.txt') -replace ',',"`r`n" | Set-Content 'D:\ServerName.txt'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This oneliner is working for me:

```
(Get-Content "Path\test.txt") -replace ',',"`r`n" | Out-File "Path\test.txt"
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `-replace ',', [Environment]::NewLine` instead